# Combining multiple genetic operators

Tags: genetic-algorithm, heuristics, genetic-programming

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it is my understanding that crossovers tend to lead towards local optima, while mutation increases the random walk of the search thus tend to help in escaping local optima tendencies. This insight I got from reading the following: [Introduction to Genetic Algorithms](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~nd/surprise_96/journal/vol1/hmw/article1.html) and [Wikipedia's article on Genetic Operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_operator#Combining_operators).

My question is, what is the best or most ideal way to pick which individuals go through crossover and which go through mutation? Is there a rule of thumb for this? What are the implications?

Thanks in advance. This is a pretty specific question that is a bit hard to Google with (for me at least).

Answer (score 1):

The selection of individuals to participate in crossover operation must consider the fitness, that is "better individuals are more likely to have more child programs than inferior individuals.":
http://cswww.essex.ac.uk/staff/rpoli/gp-field-guide/23Selection.html#7_3

The most common way to perform this is using Tournament Selection (see wikipedia).

Selection of the individuals to mutate should not consider fitness, in fact, should be random. And the number of elements mutated per generation (mutation rate) should be very low, around 1% (or it may fall into random search):
http://cswww.essex.ac.uk/staff/rpoli/gp-field-guide/24RecombinationandMutation.html#7_4

In my experience, tweaking the tournament parameters just a bit could lead to substantial changes in the final results (for better or for worse), so it is usually a good idea to play with these parameters until you find a "sweet spot".

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Might have missed this in my lectures or something. But your remark regarding mutation and how it should only happen at a very low rate is something my professor might have skipped. Thanks!

Comment: I never selected individuals for mutation randomly. My GAs usually select an individual, then determine whether crossover occurs. If it does I select another individual, and cross them over, producing the child(ren). Then for each of the children (or the first selected individual if xover didn't occur) I determine whether it is going to be mutated. To sum up, each individual is 1) not crossed, not mutated, or 2) crossed, not mutated, or 3) not crossed, mutated, or 4) crossed and mutated. GAs are kind of alchemy, you just have to try what works for your domain.

Comment: If you "visit" the individuals one by one, how can you determine if they are apt to be involved in crossover? I mean, it sounds difficult without knowing the relative fitness.

Comment: And yes, GA and GP in a way are kind of alchemy. That is one of the reasons why I found them extremely interesting :)